# Building mongodb C driver on MacOS

Tags: c, macos, mongodb, driver

I tried this:

```
git clone git://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver.git 
cd mongo-c-driver 
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
```

Output:

```
Error: libtoolize was not found on your system. Cannot continue.
On Darwin, this is named glibtoolize
Submodule 'src/libbson' (git://github.com/mongodb/libbson.git) registered for path 'src/libbson'
Cloning into 'src/libbson'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 5211, done.
remote: Counting objects: 66, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (65/65), done.
remote: Total 5277 (delta 35), reused 2 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (5277/5277), 5.18 MiB | 2.22 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3463/3463), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'src/libbson': checked out '5fafb63060b08c477fa8e243e07de40869de691d'
Error: libtoolize was not found on your system. Cannot continue.
On Darwin, this is named glibtoolize
Error: autoreconf not found, please install it.
Error: autoreconf not found, please install it.
```

How can I fix this?  (Sorry...not normally a C guy, so use small words.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `libtool`. The easiest is to do it with Homebrew. If you don't already have Homebrew installed, you can install it with a simple command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

You can find more information on the [site](http://brew.sh/). When Homebrew is installed, you can install `libtool` easily:

```
brew install libtool
```

Comment: Well, that got me farther down the road, but now I'm getting other errors when I run autogen: configure:5861: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_STATIC
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure:5862: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL
configure:5863: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL

Comment: That means it still can't find `libtool`. I just tested compilation, I only needed to install `libtool` and `automake`.

Comment: Hmm, then I'm missing something.  I used brew to install autoconf 2.69, automake 1.14.1, and libtool 2.4.2, then set my PATH to include the bin dirs of all of these (i.e. they're found if I do a 'which lib tool it's returning the expected one in /usr/local/Cellar (brew's install point)).  I'm still getting the error tho.

Comment: I don't have any ideas then, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager for Mac

```
brew install mongo-c
```